# How to Read and Write Data from Firebase Database?

Tags: firebase, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have many problems to read data from a simple Firebase DB and to store it.
    It's the first time that I use it so any help will be appreciated.

The solution is Xamarin.Forms and this is the Android part, my main problem.

This is my DB Structure:

[image]

I need to read and write the "number" value stored.

I add all Firebase package like Firebase.Database and Firebase.Connection

In my Android Prj I have a class with these:

```
MainActivity.cs

    private void InitFirebaseAuth()
    {
      var options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
      .SetApplicationId("******")
      .SetApiKey("*******")
      .SetDatabaseUrl("******")
      .Build();
      if (app == null)
       app = FirebaseApp.InitializeApp(this, options, "SaloneB");

    }

FirebaseHelper.cs
DatabaseReference databaseReference;
FirebaseDatabase database

public void Connect()
{
    database = FirebaseDatabase.GetInstance(MainActivity.app);
}

First I call Connect then I try something like this without result:

FirebaseClient firebase = new FirebaseClient("*****");
//This to retrieve value
var items = await firebase
.Child("number_of_user") //name of the table
.OnceAsync(); //retrieve the value

Items result is 0 elements
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Try to use the following code to retrieve the data:`await firebase.Child(table_name).OnceAsync<User>()).Select(item => new User{...}).ToList();`. You could google the keyword as **Getting started with Xamarin Forms and Firebase Databases** to check the related tutorial.

Comment: I use the Firebase.Net Plugin and I've resolved.

Comment: You could post your solution and mark it as the answer. It'll help others who face the similar problem.